# Как вставить флеш ролик в html?

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте, как можно вставить флеш ролик в `html` страницу и каким форматом ролик должен быть закодирован? Меня интересует флеш ролик в виде баннера.

Answer (score 3):

Для того, чтобы все работало кроссбраузерно, `Flash`-ролик нужно вставить с использованием обоих тегов: `object` и `embed`, например так:

```
<object
    id="BridgeMovie" width="400" height="200"       
    classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"  
 codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab">
    <param name="movie" value="bridge.swf" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
    <embed
        src="bridge.swf"
        name="BridgeMovie" align="middle"
        play="true" loop="false" quality="high" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
        width="400" height="200" scale="exactfit"
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
        pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
    </embed>
</object>
```

В этом примере существенны детали:

- Имя ролика `BridgeMovie` дублируется как `object.id` и `embed.name`.
- Путь к ролику `bridge.swf` дублируется в `object/embed`.
- Параметр `allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"`.
- Дублируются размеры ролика

[Связь JS с объектом Flash](http://javascript.ru/unsorted/bridge-to-flash#svyaz-js-s-obektom-flash)

[Тег object](http://htmlbook.ru/html/object)